# Making a web application open source

Tags: php, jquery, git, open-source, licensing

I have worked for quite a long time on a web app, some kind of CMS and Intranet portal developped in PHP/MySQL with jQuery.
At the moment, the repository is under SVN, but I think I will migrate on GIT before making it public. I am wondering if some of you might know what's the best method, or just give some advices, or share some links regarding the fact of making a web app public, and trying to attract developers on the project.

I don't know which license I will be using (GPL, MIT ?), neither the platform on which I want it to be hosted (Sourceforge, Github, Google code). Any advice about that would be great too.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you planning to do this? Your motivation will play a large part in your licensing decision.

Comment: The 2 reasons pointed by mzabski are both right to me. I would support open-source ideologically, and I don't think it's right to use opened and free tools (PHP, MySQL, jQuery) to achieve applications where you close the code. And of course I hope this project will be found useful, and attract potential contributors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 4):

I have very good experience with Google Code. It is fast, has no technical issues and the online interface is very clean and easy to use (unlike SourceForge).

I recommend either GPL or AGPL license.

AGPL is Affero GPL. It is pretty much the same as GPL, except anyone who publicly uses modified version has to provide its source code. For example if some company made extensive modifications to the code only for its own website/project, it would not be forced to release the changed source code if you used only GPL. But under AGPL, the company would have to release code even though it didn't distribute the application, but used it on its own server only - contributing to the public code base. This could deter some potential users from corporate sector though, so you have to weigh its advantages and disadvantages!

EDIT: Just for inspiration, there is list of projects using AGPL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AGPL_web_applications

EDIT 2: Reacting on comment by David Dorward on the question.

There are two possible reasons why you would want to choose open license.

1) **Political**. You want to go open, because open is the *morally right* way to go. You should choose AGPL or even MIT License.

2) **Practical**. You want attention and people using your project. Open source projects gather attention much more easily that similar closed source (or even commercial) projects. If your project is looking promising, you may get people who will actively contribute into code base - for free. Also, distributing free PHP closed source application is somewhat complicated (though not entirely impossible). GPL is the way to go.

EDIT 3: I recommend this free book: [Producing Open Source Software](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproducingoss.com%2F&ei=nH49TdubGMfsOYzHzdQL&usg=AFQjCNHI4tMoARbJ4lKFjML1GAMt7Y8HGA&sig2=eOO9vlSyFtrFsLrjS9MO1w)

Comment: Interesting... I had never heard of that Affero license. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it is great license, but barely any projects are using  it. I have heard of several cases where project leaders regretted that their project is GPL, not AGPL - usually after someone improved the software, but refused to release the source codes (because they ran it on their server only).

Answer (score 1):

MIT licensing means the developers can take your code and do pretty much what they want with it, with no obligations to give credit to you for the code they reuse. So you may want a stricter license than that. GNU GPL usually works well.

As for the hosting platform, I would recommend GitHub. From what I've seen, it has the biggest potential to get developers to contribute, thanks to its simple tools for forking a project and submitting changes back to the source.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, MIT license is out :) And from what I've read so far, everyone seems very emphatic about GitHub. I'll need to go through some doc about GIT though.